# How to hide some phing targets from xml

Tags: php, xml, target, phing

i have about 25 phing targets, when i list them in the console.

But 5 of them are just needed by other targets and i will never trigger them alone.

is there a possibility to hide them?

For example:

There are the targets:
    cms.cc
    cc-config
    cc-content
    cc-service

The all pop up in my list, but "cc"-target is the only one i will trigger.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't test it myself, but according a [testcase](http://www.phing.info/trac/browser/trunk/test/etc/components/Target/HiddenTargets.xml) I found via Google I guess, that there is a (not documented) attribute `hidden`

```
<target hidden="true" />
```

Comment: hi, it doesn't work for me. BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file [wrapped: /srv/htdocs/trunk/applications/fe/etc/build.xml:21:113: Unexpected attribute 'hidden']
Total time: 0.0630 seconds

Comment: phing 2.5 could solve this problem i thnk. your attribute is written here: http://www.phing.info/trac/browser/branches/2.5/test/etc/components/Target/HiddenTargets.xml?rev=1013&order=size

Answer (score 2):

Using the suggested target attribute `hidden` with them values `true|false` while hide them from `phing -l` since Phing version *2.4.3*.

Answer (score 1):

There's attribute `hidden` for targets. It [was documented](https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/946) starting from version `2.4.13`.

It's well described in the section [H.2 Targets](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html) and subsection *H.2.2 Attributes*:

> **hidden**    |   Boolean | Whether or not to include this target in the list of targets generated by phing -l | Default: *False* | Required: *No*

Currently available arguments are well documented as well in [A.2 Command Line Arguments](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html) section:

> **-l -list**
>
> List all available targets in buildfile (excluding targets that have their `hidden` attribute set to `true`)

Example of usage is next:

```
<target name="project-target" description="meaningful description" hidden="true">
    ...
</target>
```